# Example of homomorphism $\underset{\alpha \in A}{\ast} \pi_1(U_\alpha) \to \pi_1(X)$, where $U_\alpha \ni x_0$ are an open cover of $(X,x_0)$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-explanation, fundamental-groups, free-groups

I’m reading a passage leading up to the Van Kampen’s theorem, and I have trouble understanding the settings. Here’s the materials.

> Let us consider a pointed space $\left(X, x_{0}\right)$ with an open cover $\left\{U_{\alpha}: \alpha \in A\right\}$ by path-connected open sets $U_{\alpha} \ni x_{0}$ containing the basepoint. We fix the basepoint $x_{0}$ throughout, using it for $X$ and for each $U_{\alpha},$ as well as for their intersections; we omit it from the notation for fundamental groups. The inclusions $U_{\alpha} \hookrightarrow X$ induce homomorphisms $j_{\alpha}: \pi_{1}\left(U_{\alpha}\right) \rightarrow \pi_{1}(X) .$ By the universal property of the free product, these combine to give a homomorphism
> $$\varphi: F:=\underset{\alpha \in A}{*} \pi_{1}\left(U_{\alpha}\right) \rightarrow \pi_{1}(X)$$
> Consider now, the inclusions $U_{\alpha} \cap U_{\beta} \hookrightarrow U_{\alpha}($ for $\alpha, \beta \in A)$. These induce homomorphisms
> $$
> i_{\alpha \beta}: \pi_{1}\left(U_{\alpha} \cap U_{\beta}\right) \rightarrow \pi_{1}\left(U_{\alpha}\right)
> $$
>
> The inclusions of $U_{\alpha} \cap U_{\beta}$ into $X$ via $U_{\alpha}$ or $U_{\beta}$ commute:
>
> [image]
>
> By functoriality, the same is true of the induced homomorphisms:
>
> [image]
>
> That is, for all $\alpha, \beta \in A$ we have
> $$
> j_{\alpha} \circ i_{\alpha \beta}=j_{\beta} \circ i_{\beta \alpha}: \pi_{1}\left(U_{\alpha} \cap U_{\beta}\right) \rightarrow \pi_{1}(X)
> $$
> This implies that for any loop $\sigma \in \pi_{1}\left(U_{\alpha} \cap U_{\beta}\right)$ we have
> $$
> \varphi\left(i_{\alpha \beta}(\sigma)\right)=\varphi\left(i_{\beta \alpha}(\sigma)\right) \in \pi_{1}(X)
> $$
> Thus the two-letter word $i_{\alpha \beta}(\sigma) i_{\beta \alpha}(\sigma)^{-1}=i_{\alpha \beta}(\sigma) i_{\beta \alpha}\left(\sigma^{-1}\right)$
> in the free group $F= \underset{\alpha}{\ast} \pi_{1}\left(U_{\alpha}\right)$ is in the kernel of $\varphi$.

My questions are as follows:

1. Just to be sure, are the maps $i$ and $j$ just the inclusions of homotopy classes of loops from one fundamental group to another?
2. What does the map $\varphi$ do exactly? I have trouble understanding how the maps $j_\alpha$ and $j_\beta$ “combine” to give the map $\varphi$.
3. Perhaps an example would make the idea clearer. Please use the following setting if it makes sense: say $U_\alpha$ and $U_\beta$ are both homeomorphic to $S^1$, and $a$ and $b$ are the generators of their respective fundamental groups. A word in $F$ could be something like $a^3b^{-5}$. What are the remaining components of the second diagram above, and the corresponding image of $\varphi$? If this doesn’t make sense, please let me know why and offer another example if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes
2. $\phi$ takes a free product (or word) $\Pi_\alpha \ \gamma_\alpha$ of loops $\gamma_\alpha \in \pi_1(U_\alpha)$ to the product $\Pi_\alpha \ j_\alpha(\gamma_\alpha) \in \pi_1(X)$ where the product in $\pi_1(X)$ is concatenation of loops. It's really only the maps $j$ which combine to give $\phi$.
3. This question doesn't really make sense, it's impossible to say what the space $X$ is from this situation. If $X = U_0 = U_1 = S^1$ then we have that $\phi(a^3b^{-5}) = a^{3-5} = a^{-2}$ assuming $a = b$.

More clearly, $\phi: \mathbb Z* \mathbb Z \rightarrow \mathbb Z$ in this situation is the identity on each of the copies of $\mathbb Z$ so takes a word of integers to its product (really sum) in $\mathbb Z$.

If you don't understand something I would be happy to elaborate.

Comment: I have trouble mostly with the last assertions in the text. Specifically: 1. the claim that $\varphi\left(i_{\alpha \beta}(\sigma)\right)=\varphi\left(i_{\beta \alpha}(\sigma)\right) \in \pi_{1}(X)$, for $\sigma$ is a loop in $\pi_{1}\left(U_{\alpha} \cap U_{\beta}\right)$; 2. the equality $i_{\alpha \beta}(\sigma) i_{\beta \alpha}(\sigma)^{-1}=i_{\alpha \beta}(\sigma) i_{\beta \alpha}\left(\sigma^{-1}\right)$; and 3. the claim that this word is in the kernel of $\varphi$.

Comment: Regarding 1., what’s not clear to me is how the combination of the maps $j$ take place. Under the setting in the text, all the loops we consider are in $U_\alpha \cap U_\beta$. So I fail to see the need to distinguish between the homotopy class of this loop being in $\pi_1(U_\alpha)$ or in $\pi_1(U_\beta)$, and hence how the distinction between $j_\alpha$ and $j_\beta$ matters. It seems to me all the $j$’s and $\varphi$ are saying the same thing.

Comment: Regarding 2. and 3., I’ve just read up on the kernels of group homomorphisms, so the answers to those questions are now clear. Only question 1. in my first comment remains.

Comment: What do you not understand about question 1? @ensbana What you said is true. They are just inclusions of loops into the bigger space.

Comment: I think I have trouble here because I don’t fully understand the group $F$, and its relationship with $\pi_1(U_\alpha)$ and $\pi_1(U_\beta)$. Would it be correct to explain it this way?

Comment: Say we have a loop $a$ in $\pi_1(U_\alpha)$ and $b$ in $\pi_1(U_\beta)$. Those two are mapped by $j_\alpha$ and $j_\beta$ to $a$ and $b$ in $\pi_1(X)$, respectively. Also, the injection from $\pi_1(U_\alpha)$ to $F$ maps $a$ to $a$ (technically $ae_\beta$), and similarly the injection from $\pi_1(U_\beta)$ to $F$ maps $b$ to $b$ (technically $e_\alpha b$). The product in $F$ of those two elements is $ab$, which must mapped by $\varphi$ also to $a \cdot b$ in $\pi_1(X)$. Is this how the “combination” of the maps $j$’s take place?

Comment: Also if we have a word like $ab$ in $F$ to start with, we can’t really get it via just the injections from $\pi_1(U_\alpha)$ and $\pi_1(U_\beta)$ alone, but it must come about as the product of two letters $a$ and $b$, like presented above?

Comment: Yes your understanding is 100% correct. @ensbana